# Unknown provider: firebaseSimpleLoginProvider

Tags: angularjs, firebase-authentication, firebasesimplelogin

I am following this [AngularJs & Firebase App](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391) tutorial and have run into a Unknown provider: firebaseSimpleLoginProvider error. The tutorial is a few years outdated so I've updated my script references and would like to know if that is the reason I am receiving an error message or if there is something else in my code that i've done incorrectly.

CDNs:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.4/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
```

apps.js:

```
var myApp = angular
    .module('angularjsFirebaseApp', ['firebase', 'ngRoute'
  ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .when('app/about', {
                templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                controller: 'AboutCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
```

main.js:

```
'use strict';


//angular.module('angularjsFirebaseApp')

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseSimpleLogin', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {

    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://vivid-heat-2200.firebaseapp.com");

    $scope.SignIn = function ($scope) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $scope.user.email,
            password = $scope.user.password;

        loginObj.$login('password', {
                email: username,
                password: password
            })
            .then(function (user) {
                console.log('Auth successful');
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Auth failure');
            });
    }


    }]);
```

Comment: `firebase-simple-login.js` hasn't been a thing for a year or so. Instead of following an outdated tutorial, may I suggest that you follow the one that comes directly from the creators of AngularFire: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html

Comment: thank you @FrankvanPuffelen